# PHP Saving a wav file

Tags: php, audio

I have a wav stream(not file) in php that comes from another server. When i want to save the stream as wav file. It does not play, the file is corrupted. Can anybody help me? The code is:

```
$file = "/var/www/sounds/soundFile.wav";
$handle  = fopen($file, 'wb')
or die('Cannot create sound file: ' . $file);
//stream_set_write_buffer($handle, 0);
fwrite($handle, $soundResult );
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of what you want to do, but ... Here is may-be what you're looking for :

```
//send file contents
$handle=fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/var/www/sounds/soundFile.wav", "rb");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.wav"');
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize(dirname(__FILE__) . "/var/www/sounds/soundFile.wav")."    ");
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```